# Flex4.6 StyleableTextField ignores <br> and <p> tags

Tags: html, apache-flex, mobile, tags, flex4

I've got a StyleableTextField in my mobile project, which gets filled with html text using the .htmlText property.

The  tag is working fine for me, but simple line breaks or paragraphs are simply ignored. What can I do about that?

Basically, the simplest HTML will just be displayed as a single line:

```
textField.htmlText = "<p>this should be the first line</p><p>this the second one</p>";
```

Again, the output is a single line.

The Flex 3 doc states that those tags are definitely supported, so I reckon they simply removed it in the newer versions (which is kinda ridiculous!).
I don't want to use the stagewebview, so what other ways to I have to properly format HTML using the StyleableTextField, or is there a simple replacement for the aforementioned tags?

Thank you very much guys!

Comment: Is `multiline` set to `true`?

Comment: Your sir, are a genius! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `multiline` is set to `true`, otherwise it will treat it as a single line of text, effectively ignoring the formatting.